# How to store personal data on my website and prevent it from being publicly accessible?

Tags: https, api, storage

My goal is pretty simple: I would like to store some personal data on a cloud server, and privately access it from client applications.

As a front-end and mobile developer, I have all the needed knowledge to access this data by using an API with some private keys, and using it. However, on the server-side, I only know how to create a website and add pages and resources to it with FTP clients like Filezilla. I would like to have more information on what I am supposed to use for this situation.

Specifically, how to securely store my data, like if it is available from a URL like `https://www.myurl.com/files/1.jpg`, how to protect this file from being publicly accessible, and create the necessary API to access it from a client app.

Thank you for your help!

PS: also, I am sorry if this is not the right place to ask this question, which I know is very generic, but I have no idea where to do so otherwise.

Comment: You should be doing it as a webservice or rest calls

Comment: JamesDerrick, you've answered your question by yourself: _"I have all the needed knowledge to access this data by using an API with some private keys, and using it"_

Comment: Apologies, but I don't think this is on topic here - its specific to a single website and the question lacks detail.    There are many ways of doing this, the easiest being a .htaccess file with basic authentication.  On the other extreme would be to use webdav along with a webdav client.  That said, do you really need to reinvent the wheel?  Programs like Nextcloud might do this all for you... even including sync clients.